# Spring Data MongoDB document expiry time

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I've set up a simple document model (below) along with a Spring Data repository

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserDocument {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    @Indexed(expireAfterSeconds=3600)
    private LocalDateTime registeredDate;
}
```

This seems to work fine and deletes the user documents after whatever time I set `expireAfterSeconds` to. However, rather than typing in a value of 3600 I'd like to pull that number from a config .yml. The usual way of adding `@Value("${config.file.path.of.expiry}")` won't work because `@Indexed`requires the value to be a runtime constant, which @Value isn't.

Is there any other way to set up document expiry dates in Spring/Mongodb that doesn't use `@Indexed(expireAfterSeconds=x)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `Indexed` annotation to declare an index which Spring Data Mongo will create on your behalf ... you could create the index explicitly using a `MongoTemplate` instance.

```
@Value("${config.file.path.of.expiry}")
long expireAfterSeconds;

...

mongoTemplate.indexOps("users").ensureIndex(
    new Index().on("registeredDate", Order.ASCENDING)
        .expire(expireAfterSeconds)
);
```

This would allow you to source the value for `expireAfterSeconds` from a configuration file at runtime rather than hardcoding it in an annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would this need to be done in an @Configuration class? I'll give it a shot

Comment: It wouldn't have to be done in a @Configuration class. Any class which (a) is Spring managed (and hence can be 'provided' with an @Value) and (b) has access to a MongoTemplate and (c) can be invoked before you start using the collection you want to index should suffice.